# What does the phrase "run on to" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Here is a sentence from a text describing a football match:

> You can play the ball along the floor for your winger **to run on to**.

Any suggestions on the meaning of the phrase "to run on to" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a common phrase in football. The meaning might not be obvious at first, but once you understand it it's actually quite a literal description. It describes a type of pass typically played towards a team mate who is already running.

Instead of being passed directly towards the player's feet, the ball is passed into empty space *ahead* of the player, at the right speed for the ball to reach that space at the same time as the player. The receiving player has to literally *run on to* the trajectory of the pass.